# Importing a module replaces the UI (angular)

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-module

I have 2 modules. Graph and Customer.

Recently started following the mono repo structure and now I can't import modules without them changing the whole UI. The routing (url) remains the same.

The location of GraphModule is in apps>core>src>app>central>graph>graph.module.ts and the location for the Customer is in libs>web>customer>ui>src>lib>customer-ui.module.ts

Is there anyway for me to use the graph module without change UI for the customer?

Comment: unless you have conflicting routes in the modules, or some other non-standard behavior, then adding another module shouldn't change your UI.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same project then you can import a module to another module. otherwise, you can use The open() method of the Window interface for the routing.

Comment: It is in the same project but importing it changes the whole UI.